# Question About Systemic Culture

Tags: terminology

I have a question about Systemic Culture in the context of aviation. What is a systemic culture, and how is a systemic culture related to the aviation industry?

Answer (score 4):

This one is easy. Go read the primary cause of the horrific [crash of two 747's at Tenerife in 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster), and why the F/O of the KLM aircraft did not override the actions of the alleged highly-experienced captain, [Jacob Louis Veldhuyzen van Zanten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Veldhuyzen_van_Zanten). Everything can be tied to a systemic culture that severely discouraged such actions, even in the face of an imminent disaster. This accident led to many changes in virtually all western commercial airlines to address this specific issue.

Comment: Still a big problem in places like Russia and China, and to a lesser extent, other parts of world outside Europe and the Anglosphere.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, I agree.